# Android Trouble with Edit Text Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my application,on press of a button "Add contact" phone book gets open and then user selects a contact that get displayed in Edittext View and when another button "Add More Contacts" is pressed, a another Edit-Text View gets displayed on the top for which i can again select the contact from phone book. But the problem that i am facing is that i want that user can only add up to 5 Edit Text .
I am using the following code, but its force crashing the application. Please help.
And also i want the Edit Text Views to be non editable, for which i tried `editable=false` but its working only for the first Edit Text View not on the other Views, that user adds afterwards.

```
int id = 1;


             layoutLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
                btn_addmore_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddmorecontacts);
                btn_addmore_cntct.setOnClickListener(OnClick());
                EditText editview = new EditText(this);
                editview.setText("Add more");
                editview.setEnabled(false);
                editview.setFocusable(false);

            }

            // implementing OnClickListener OnClick() method for "btn_addmore_cntct"
            // button
            private OnClickListener OnClick() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // changing return type "null" to "new OnClickListner"
                return new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        if(layoutLinear.getChildCount()>5){

                        }else{
                            final EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                            tab.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tab.setId(id);
                            id++;
        layoutLinear.addView(tab,0);
    tab.requestFocus();
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following way.

```
int temp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstance) {  
    super.onCreate(savedinstance);  
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    temp=1;
    layoutLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
    btn_addmore_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddmorecontacts);
    btn_addmore_cntct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(temp<=5){
               EditText tab = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
               tab.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
               tab.setEnabled(false);
               tab.setFocusable(false);
               layoutLinear.addView(tab);
               temp++;
       }else{
           //Print message to user Cant add more editText.

        }

        }
    });
}
```

Let me know its working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Just check number of `layoutLinear` child

```
if(layoutLinear.getChildCount()>5){

     //nothing to do
}else{
  //create new EditText and add to layoutLinear
}
```

user this code to disable EditText

```
edittext.setEnabled(false);
edittext.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: this is how i have implemented your code, but its only adding 1 Edit Text View only.